# Forma correcta de realizar la persistencia de varias entidades con el mínimo número de servicios y repositorios

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Pues la pregunta es como puedo realizar un "CrudService" que administre varias entidades y tenga persistencia a través de un "BasicRepository". voy a intentar aclarar con un ejemplo y sigo explicando debajo.

**Directorios**

```
com
  |_ example
        |_ controller
        |       |_ Entity1Controller.java
        |       |_ Entity2Controller.java
        |
        |_ model
        |     |_ entity
        |     |      |_ Entity1.java
        |     |      |_ Entity2.java
        |     |
        |     |_ repository
        |            |_ BasicRepository.java
        |
        |_ service
        |      |_ CrudService.java
        |
        |_ExampleStackOverflowApplication.java
```

**Entidades**

*Entity1 y Entity2 son exactamente iguales para facilitar un poco el ejemplo.*

```java
@Entity
public class Entity1 implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
// Constructor, Getters y Setters
}
```

**Controllers**

*Entity1Controller y Entity2Controller son exactamente iguales para facilitar un poco el ejemplo.*

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/entity1")
public class Entity1Controller {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("CrudService")
    private CrudService<Entity1, Integer> crudService;
    
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAll() {
        List<Entity1> entities = crudService.getAllEntities();
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;
        return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(entities);
    }
//Resto de los métodos para completar un CRUD
}
```

**CrudService**

```java
@Service("CrudService")
public class CrudService<T, ID> {

    @Autowired
    private BasicRepository<T, ID> repository;


    public List<T> getAllEntities() {
        return repository.count() == 0 ? null: (List<T>) repository.findAll();
    }
//Resto de métodos para completar un CRUD
}
```

**BasicRepository**

```java
@Repository("BasicRepository")
public interface BasicRepository<T, ID> extends CrudRepository<T, ID>{
}
```

El flujo de la información en el programa es el siguiente:

`Controller -> Service -> Repository -> Database`

La cuestión es: En el Controller llama al Servicio usando tipos genéricos, osea cuando el Servicio es creado en la linea `private CrudService<Entity1, Integer> crudService;` estamos declarando los objetos que van a tomar esos genéricos, dentro de Service, esos genéricos ya tienen valores, que se asignar también al Repositorio a través de la siguiente linea: `private BasicRepository<T, ID> repository;`.

El problema es que si ejecuto este programa da este error al iniciar:

**Error**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-09 02:54:14.995 ERROR 36132 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entity1Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'crudService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'CrudService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BasicRepository' defined in com.example.model.repository.BasicRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:923) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.example.ExampleApplication.main(ExampleApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'CrudService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BasicRepository' defined in com.example.model.repository.BasicRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BasicRepository' defined in com.example.model.repository.BasicRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:75) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:229) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:179) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:162) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:281) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$6(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:326) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Realmente me interesa, ya que a lo poco que crezca una aplicación acabas realizando una cantidad muy grande de clases que hacen exactamente lo mismo, por eso se me ocurrió lo de usar tipos genéricos, pero no funcionan como yo espero.

Mi pregunta sería: **¿Como sería la forma correcta de realizar la persistencia de esas entidades con el mínimo numero de servicios y repositorios?**

Requerimientos:

- Java 15
- Spring
- Spring Tool Suite
- Mysql 8.0

Un saludo y gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoy día con la experiencia obtenida estos años soy capaz de auto-responderme esta pregunta.

Mi problema en aquel momento era no entender como funcionaban los tipos genéricos. Debía arrastrarlos hasta el controlador usando clases abstractas que debía extender para tener las implementaciones especificas.

Dejo el código correctamente comentado para hacer esta respuesta lo mas entendible posible para las próximas personas que deseen implementar genéricos en sus proyectos en Spring Framework.

Además en este ejemplo también incluiré servicios básicos como conversores de Entidad a DTO y viceversa.

Realizaremos el ejemplo con las clases abstractas y la implementación para un usuario.

Empezamos con el repositorio.

**UserRepository.class**

```
// Definimos la clase de la entidad y el tipo de su primary key.
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {

    // Método de ejemplo en la interfaz.
    Optional<UserEntity> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Seguimos con la entidad

**UserEntity.class**

```java
@Entity
public class UserEntity {

    // Propiedades de ejemplo.
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String password;

    // A partir de aquí se encuentran los getters, setters, constructores y toString.

}
```

Ahora vamos a ver el DTO para la entidad de usuario.

**UserDTO.class**

```java
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class UserDTO {

    // Propiedades de ejemplo.
    private String name;    
    private String username;
    private String password;

    // A partir de aquí se encuentran los getters, setters, constructores y toString.

}
```

Una vez establecidas estas tres clases, es cuando podemos empezar a trabajar con tipos genéricos, para así ahorrarnos escribir código redundante por cada entidad a la que le queramos hacer un CRUD básico (en este ejemplo).

Empezaremos con la clase abstracta del conversor de DTO a Entidad.

**AbstractDtoConverter.java**

```java
// Aquí hacemos uso de dos tipos genéricos: "E" y "D". 
// En nuestro caso el tipo generico E va a representar una entidad.
// Y el tipo generico D representará el DTO de esa entidad.
public abstract class DtoConverter<E, D> {
    
    // Metodo que debemos implementar por cada par Entidad-DTO
    public abstract E fromDto(D dto);
    
    // Metodo que debemos implementar por cada par Entidad-DTO
    public abstract D fromEntity(E entity);
    
    // Aqui, teniendo las implementaciones en las clases hijas, podemos aprovechar los tipos genericos para que nos construya un conversor de listas. 
    public List<D> fromEntities(List<E> entities) {
    // Creamos una lista de DTOS cualesquiera.
        List<D> dtos = new ArrayList<D>();

    // Por cada entidad vamos a llamar al método previamente definido en una subclase y lo agregamos a la lista.
        entities.forEach(entity -> {
            dtos.add(this.fromEntity(entity));
        });

        // Para finalizar, devolvemos la lista.
        return dtos;
    }
    
        // Para el caso contrario, convertir una lista de DTO a entidades, tambien podemos usar la implementacion realizada en la subclase. 
    public List<E> fromDtos(List<D> dtos) {

        // Lista de entidades del tipo E.
        List<E> entities = new ArrayList<E>();

         // Por cada dto vamos a llamar al método previamente definido en una subclase y lo agregamos a la lista.
        dtos.forEach(dto -> {
            entities.add(this.fromDto(dto));
        });

        // Para finalizar, devolvemos la lista.
        return entities;
    }
}
```

La implementación de esta clase abstracta para nuestra entidad `UserEntity` y nuestro DTO `UserDTO` sería la siguiente:

**UserConverter.class**

```java
// Anotamos con service en este caso, ya que inyectaremos esta clase como dependencia en otras clases.
// Como se puede ver, extendemos a nuestra clase abstracta pasando entre los operadores de diamante nuestras dos clases.
@Service
public class UserConverter extends AbstractDtoConverter<UserEntity, UserDTO> {

    // Implementamos ambos metodos de la superclase
    @Override
    public User fromDto(UserDTO dto) {
        UserEntity user  = new UserEntity();

        user.setName(dto.getName());
        user.setUsername(dto.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(dto.getPassword());

        return user;
    }



    @Override
    public UserDTO fromEntity(UserEntity entity) {
        UserDTO dto = new UserDTO();
    
        dto.setName(entity.getName());
        dto.setUsername(entity.getUsername());
        dto.setPassword(entity.getPassword());
        
        return dto;
    }

    // Gracias a esto que acabamos de hacer, además de estos dos métodos, también tenemos los de la super clase, que son capaces de convertir listas.

}
```

Ahora vamos a por el servicio que va a controlar a nuestra Entidad y todo lo relacionado con ella para poder realizar un CRUD y vamos a explotar al máximo nuestros tipos genéricos.

**AbstractBaseService.class**

```java
// Esta será la clase abstracta de la que heredaran el resto de servicios que usaremos para el resto de entidades.
public abstract class AbstractBaseService<E, D, DC extends AbstractDtoConverter<E, D>, R extends JpaRepository<E, ID>, ID> {

    /* Os dejo lo que representan cada uno de los genéricos.
     * 
     * E -> Nuestra entidad.
     * D -> Nuestro DTO.
     * DC -> Nuestro servicio que hereda de la clase AbstractDtoConverter.
     * ID -> El tipo de ID que usa nuestra entidad.
     * R -> El repositorio que hereda de JpaRepository (La primera interfaz que creamos).
     */

    // Como lo indicamos en los genericos, nuestro repositorio será "R"
    @Autowired
    protected R repository;

    // Nuestro converter se inyectará como el que pasemos en los operadores de diamante.
    @Autowired
    protected DC DtoConverter;

    // Voy a crear 5 métodos de ejemplo de operaciones comunes.
    
    // Encuentra una Entidad segun su tipo de primary key, y lo devuelve como el DTO correspondiente.
    public D findById(ID id) {
        return DtoConverter.fromEntity(repository.findById(id).get());
    }

    // En este caso, haciendo uso del metodo la clase abstracta AbstractDTOConverter y los tipos genericos, 
    // extraemos todas las entidades de la base de datos y las convertimos a una lista de DTOs.
    public List<D> findAll() {
        return DtoConverter.fromEntities(repository.findAll());
    }

    // En la operacion de guardar un dato en la base de datos segn su dto, lo hacemos gracias al conversor y al repository asignados en los operadores de diamantes.
    public D save(D d) {
        
        //Convert to Entity to save in BBDD
        E entity = DtoConverter.fromDto(d);
        
        // Return response in DTO Format.
        return DtoConverter.fromEntity(repository.save(entity));
    }

    // El resto de ejemplos siguen las mismas dinamicas.

    public D edit(D d) {
        //Convert to Entity to save in BBDD
        E entity = DtoConverter.fromDto(d);
        
        // Return response in DTO Format.
        return DtoConverter.fromEntity(repository.save(entity));
    }
    
    public void delete(D d) {
        repository.delete(DtoConverter.fromDto(d));
    }
```

Bien, esa clase es algo compleja de entender, así que voy a dar una nueva explicación aquí de la declaración de la clase.

- `public abstract class AbstractBaseService<>`: Con esto declaramos la clase abstracta.
- `E, D`: Con estos dos tipos genéricos, vamos a definir la Entidad y el DTO, para poder hacer métodos genéricos que funcionen con cualquier tipo.
- `DC extends AbstractDtoConverter<E, D>`: Esto será una clase que herede de AbstractDtoConverter, que a su vez recibe los dos tipos genéricos previamente definidos (así nos aseguramos que siempre trabajamos con el mismo E y D).
- `R extends JpaRepository<E, ID>`: Esto será la la interfaz repositorio (Que extiende de un repositorio de Jpa) que también recibe la entidad especifica. Tambien recibe un ID, que será el tipo de dato de la primary key de nuestra entidad (En este caso un Long).
- `ID`: Tipo de la primary key de nuestra entidad.

Y ahora es cuando sucede algo maravilloso, gracias al esqueleto que hemos ido formando. ¿Cómo será la implementación de este método para que mi entidad usuario tenga un CRUD?

**UserService.class**

```java
// Etiqueta servicio, para poder hacer autowired posteriormente.
@Service
public class UserService extends AbstractBaseService<UserEntity, UserDTO, UserConverter, UserRepository, Long> {

    // No hay mas que esto, debido a que hemos rellenado el operador de diamante, 
    // todos los metodos de la clase abstracta están ahora funcionando con lo relacionado a mi usuario.

    // Si queremos crear otra entidad, solo debemos ir creando las implementaciones hasta llegar a esta clase.
    // Además, si queremos que tenga una funcionalidad especifica además del CRUD, la podemos agrega aquí.
}
```

Para finalizar podemos ver como quedaría nuestro Controller:

**UserController.class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    protected UserService service;
    
    @Autowired
    protected UserConverter converter;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getPublicUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
    
        UserDTO dto = this.service.findById(id);            

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(dto);

    }

    // Resto del CRUD

}
```

Aquí se puede ver que una vez formado el esqueleto solo hace falta implementar la entidad, el repositorio, el dto y el conversor. El resto es extender de las clases con los tipos genéricos, donde ya implementamos la funcionalidad básica.

Esto también se puede realizar con los controladores, realizando un controlador abstracto con genéricos que después se van implementando para tener las operaciones básicas ya cubiertas (De la misma forma que hacemos en el AbstractBaseService)

Aunque esto es una solución muy buena para no reusar código, es importante tener en cuenta que no siempre es interesante hacer un CRUD completo de cada entidad que tenemos en la base de datos, además, también es muy común tener varios Dtos para cada entidad, por lo que quizás debamos abstraernos algo mas y realizar mas de una herencia de clases abstractas, lo que puede dificultar el desarrollo al comienzo.

**Por tanto, esto es solo una buena solución si estamos trabajando con entidades simples que no van a necesitar cosas especificas mas allá del CRUD.**

Espero que pueda servir a alguien. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el ejemplo y la respuesta. Finalmente pude entender este tema!